# AWK - While Loop with Two Variables and AWK Command to GREP

Tags: awk, while-loop

The command below works to essentially "grep" any line which contains "ASHBBBRJ02  ae5.0":

```
awk -F'\t' '/ASHBBBRJ02\tae5.0/' temp/phase6_lsp_comparison.txt
```

I want to read a file which contains a list of this similar strings in this format:

```
hostname1 <tab> interface1
hostname2 <tab> interface2
hostname3 <tab> interface3
```

The code below does not work or output any errors.  Can someone find my error?

```
while IFS=$'\t' read hostname interface; do
    awk -F'\t' -v hostname="$hostname" -v interface="$interface" '/hostname\tinterface/' file2
done < file1
```

Comment: change to `$0~ hostname "\t" interface`, you don't need to set `FS` as well.

Comment: Still not working and I can echo two of the fields that I'm trying to match: 

`while IFS=$'\t' read hostname interface preutil postutil criticallity; do
    echo -e "$hostname\t$interface\t$postutil" >> temp/phase8_post_interface_lsps.txt
    awk -F'\t' -v hostname="$hostname" -v interface="$interface" '$0~ hostname "\t" interface' temp/phase3_post_hops_bitrate.txt
done < temp/phase7_interfaces.txt`

Comment: Does your input file **really** have a blank character before and after every `<tab>` character as you say it does in your example? Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the problem is in your script without an actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to look at but to do what you say you're trying to do might be (no shell loop required):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    regexps[$1 FS $2]
    next
}
{
    for (regexp in regexps) {
        if ($0 ~ regexp) {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}
' temp/phase7_interfaces.txt temp/phase3_post_hops_bitrate.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with the input file not being tabbed and realized I ran the echo test against a different file.  Sorry and thank you for the code suggestions though.